# DB Mail Fails Even with no server changes

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-mail

I am baffled as to how this was working before as their is no user account set-up.  It was working this a.m., but now it is not?  Is it possible to use send-mail w/o configuring an account within SQL Server itself?  Attached is what I see in my mail window, and the error logs showing that it failed today...
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried testing SMTP from the SQL Server: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323350

Comment: @ShawnMelton - that was the culprit, for some reason the SMTP service on the server was stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Since it was working in the A.M. and it is not working in the P.M., then it seems likely that something has changed.

Possibilities:

1. The Mail Server has failed. And likely this will be harder to troubleshoot if Exchange is your mail server.
2. Somebody has changed the configuration. For example, changing the SMTP Authentication setting.
3. There is a network/firewall/etc. problem that is interfering.

Or something else altogether, of course, since I am only guessing.